# Set the current navigation to "Display the same navigation items as the parent site"

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to set the current navigation to "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" using object model? If yes, how?

publishingWeb.Navigation.thenwhat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [InheritCurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation.inheritcurrent.aspx) Property

```
publishingWeb.Navigation.InheritCurrent = True
```

[Other members of PortalNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation_members.aspx) for reference.

Comment: Your answer is correct however I dont think business unit meant that when they requested this to be enabled. Thanks Again for your prompt help.